# How to Display data of specific[ logged in user in Firebase Auth in Android Studio

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, data-retrieval

```
public class History extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView lv;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    FirebaseUser user;
    FirebaseDatabase rootnode;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    List<String> itemlist;
    String uid;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        lv = findViewById(R.id.hist);
        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();
        itemlist = new ArrayList<>();
        rootnode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Addappointment");
//        reference = rootnode.getReference("Addappointment");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                itemlist.clear();
                String pn = snapshot.child(uid).child("patname").getValue(String.class);
                String a = snapshot.child(uid).child("age").getValue(String.class);
                String g = snapshot.child(uid).child("gender").getValue(String.class);
                String ad = snapshot.child(uid).child("appday").getValue(String.class);
                String sdd = snapshot.child(uid).child("doctor").getValue(String.class);
                itemlist.add(pn);
                itemlist.add(a);
                itemlist.add(g);
                itemlist.add(ad);
                itemlist.add(sdd);

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemlist);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Network Error! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

** Whenever I open this activity my applications get close, and it never displays the details I asked for to show. such as I stored the details of the patient on real-time database firebase in other activity and want to display/retrieve those details of the specific current logged user to this activity named History**

Comment: What do you mean by "Whenever I open this activity my applications get close"? does the application crash whenever you start the activity?

Comment: yes It does crash @Tuvel

Comment: Please edit the post and provide the info from the debugger (The exception [error])

Comment: okay let me edit it @Tuvel

Comment: it is just showing Method invocation 'getUid' may produce 'NullPointerException' @Tuvel

Comment: @Tuvel can you please send me your email or any other detail where we can contact, or at zoom?